# Django Rest Framework serialize permission

Tags: django, permissions, django-rest-framework

I would like to serialize object level permission - and send a simple `True` or `False` to the  browser - so accordingly I trigger the "allow editing" code.

I am doing this so the user does not have functionality presented to them that they cannot use.

Is there a built in way to do this? The docs do not allude to this.

I have attempted the following on the serializer:

```
has_permission = serializers.SerializerMethodField('check_permission')

def check_permission(self, obj):
    return self.check_object_permissions(self.request, obj)
```

but the serializer does not have the method `check_object_permissions` - that belongs to the permission object.

Answer (score 2):

Add method to your model to check the permissions:

```
 class MyModel(models.Model):
     myfield = models.TextField(max_length=100)

     def check_permissions(self):
        # Perform your permissions functions
        if (.....):
           return True
        else: 
           return False
```

Add custom field into your Serializer as follows:

```
  class MyModelSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):        
      has_permissions = serializers.BooleanField(source='check_permissions', read_only=True)
      class Meta:
         model = models.MyModel
         fields = ("myfield","has_permissions")
```

Comment: Or, if you need to know the user, use a serializer method and access the current user via the serializer context.

Comment: this breaks layering: I would have to import rest_framework.permissions to the models.py, and unless I use odd spaghetti then I will be unable to use different permissions for the same models on different views

Comment: To maintain layering you can use Django User Auth and override the permission_denied method on the view.